# Azure Table Storage and Trigger Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-triggers

Currently I am appended entities to my Azure table storage. If at least 5 or more entities are added, what I need to do is trigger another function to retrieve all the data in the table and do some processing on them and then update the table with the post processed data. Can someone direct me towards examples or help me figure out what the trigger conditions would be?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried or read somewhere that you're not sure where to begin?

Comment: @MarkC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table. I have been looking over this link, but I dont seem to understand how to condition my function

Answer (score 1):

There is no trigger which fires directly by watching Table Storage. Some possible workarounds:

- Have a timer trigger which would check if there are 5 rows, and fire an action if yes
- When you put something in table storage, also send a message to a queue and have a Function triggered by that queue

Comment: thanks @Mikhail for your help! Would you know any specific examples I could look at?